# Is ruby's multidimensional array out of bounds behaviour consistent?

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

If I have a multidimensional array, I can exceed the bounds in the final dimension and get a nil return, but if I exceed the bounds of a non-final dimension, I receive an error. Is this by design, and if so what is the reasoning?

```
> ar = [ [00,01,02], [10,11,12], [20,21,22] ]
=> [[0, 1, 2], [10, 11, 12], [20, 21, 22]]
> ar[2][2]
=> 22
> ar[2][3]
=> nil
> ar[3][2]
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
from (irb):32
from :0
```

I understand why this is happening, but why isn't nil[] defined to return nil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if [Matz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukihiro_Matsumoto) ever documented why the `NilClass` is designed the way it is. If it's not so then we can only guess. My guess is that it is based on the behavior of Smalltalk.

`nil` could either be *message eating* or *exception throwing*. Ruby has an exception throwing nil object.

If you have a *message eating* nil then it's difficult to determine the object that was the first one to return nil in a chained call like `arr[1][2][3]`. I don't know how often this really is an issue but it seems to be a valid point. As a counterexample Objective-C seems to do just fine with a *message eating* nil.

You can patch `NilClass` to become *message eating*

```
class NilClass
  def method_missing(*)
    nil
  end
end
```

or for arrays only

```
class NilClass
  def []
    nil
  end
end
```

both makes `nil[]` return a nil and either can break existing code

```
nil[][][][]
=> nil
```

Comment: Thank you for the food for thought! I definitely thought about patching `NilClass` as you've mentioned. That would give consistent behaviour. The other option, as I see it, would be to patch `Array` to throw an `OutOfBoundsException`, but I could see how that could produce confusing results, since ruby Arrays are so flexible.

Comment: I knew I read about the Null Object Pattern in Ruby before but I didn't remember that is was @Avid that wrote it. There's some very good advice there!

Comment: Doh! I just accidentally deleted my previous comment on the [Null Object Pattern](http://devblog.avdi.org/2011/05/30/null-objects-and-falsiness/). Also, there was a neat article on _message eating_ vs. _exception throwing_ `nil` [here](http://wiki.squeak.org/squeak/5962).

Answer (score 3):

In Ruby, there are no multi-dimensional arrays. What you have there is an array, containing arrays as elements. So if you get the first "dimension", you get another array back (or nil if you exceeded the bounds of the outer array).

`nil` is an object of `NilClass` that has a finite (and small) set of defined methods. And the `[]` method, that is called when you use the `whatever[:foo]` syntax is just not defined on `NilClass`. Thus it can't return anything.

Generally, it wouldn't make sense to define all possible methods on nil as it would confuse people even more and would introduce a plethora of hard-to-detect bugs.

However if you know what you are doing and are willing to deal with the implications, you can use the [`try`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) method that is defined by some frameworks (e.g. ActiveSupport for Rails) but is not part of Ruby itself. It catches the `NoMethodError` and returns `nil` instead. In your case you could use

```
> ar[2].try(:[], 2)
=> nil
```

However, this is generally discouraged as it makes things harder to debug. Instead you should check the bounds before trying to access the array (e.g. by using `array.length`) or by using include looping constructs like `ar.each {|e| puts e}`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As I mentioned, I do understand what's going on in my example above, I just find it a strange design choice. I do think that since arrays are, as you mention, not really multidimensional arrays but just nested objects, it does complicate the matter somewhat to make consistent behaviour.